# How would you load controllers and routes after startup in mvc 6 without restarting the application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a plugin system to allow new controllers to be added at runtime. These will be api controllers and not views.

I know I can add controllers from other assemblies at startup by using the following and this works.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //Add Controllers
  var controllerAssemblies = new List<Assembly>() { typeof(Startup).Assembly };
  controllerAssemblies.AddRange(_configSettings.GetCustomAssemblies();
  services.WithControllersAsServices(controllerAssemblies);
}
```

However I need to be able to add new controllers at runtime without restarting the application.

The user would upload a new plugin and then I would like to load it so it can be used straight away without restarting or affecting any other users currently using the webservice.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)**

Comment: ...also, please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon'")**: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94251/is-it-possible-to-load-new-controllers-and-routes-after-startup-in-mvc-6

Comment: I have removed the crosspost, didn't mean to post it there.

Comment: and now that everyone has worked diligently to stack-police this post I see no one had an answer... lol